# Create and Handling a form using LOOP and POST in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to submit all values of my ,i create them using two loops but after that i'm not sure where to use the Input tag,because if a have 100 rows i want one button to submit all values and not one per line(send all values inside the tables), and after submit how to proceed to handling with this data?

Thank you for the help

```
echo "<html>";
echo"<body>";
echo"<table>";
echo "<form id='form_test' name='tabela' method='post' action=";

for($j=0;$j<=$linhas;$j++)
{
         echo"<tr>";
         for($i=0;$i<=$colunas;$i++)
         {          

                if(($i==4 || $i==6 ||$i==7) AND $j!=0)
                {
                    if($i==4)
                    {
                        echo"<td>";
                        echo "<select name='ANALISADO'>";
                        echo "<option value='$aux[$j][$i]'>".htmlspecialchars($aux[$j][$i])."</option>";
                        echo "<option value='SIM'>SIM</option>";
                        echo "</select>";
                        echo"<td>"; 
                    }
                    if($i==6)
                    {
                        echo"<td>";
                        echo "<select name='CSV_DECISAO[]'>";
                        echo "<option value='$aux[$j][$i]'>".htmlspecialchars($aux[$j][$i])."</option>";
                        echo "<option value='TROCAR OPERADORA'>TROCAR OPERADORA</option>";
                        echo "<option value='RETIRAR REMOTA'>RETIRAR REMOTA</option>";
                        echo "<option value='ALTERAR REGISTRO'>ALTERAR REGISTRO</option>";
                        echo "</select>";
                        echo"<td>"; 
                    }
                    if($i==7)
                    {
                        echo"<td>";
                        echo "<select name='CVS_DEPARTAMENTO[]'>";
                        echo "<option value='$aux[$j][$i]'>".htmlspecialchars($aux[$j][$i])."</option>";
                        echo "<option value='JURIDICO'>JURIDICO</option>";
                        echo "<option value='COMERCIAL'>COMERCIAL</option>";
                        echo "<option value='TECNICO'>TECNICO</option>";
                        echo "</select>";
                        echo"<td>"; 
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    echo"<td>".$aux[$j][$i]."<td>";
                }                   
         }
         echo"</tr>";            
}
echo"</form>";
echo"</table>";
echo"</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem (more or less)

```
//***********************************
//          CLIENT SIDE
//***********************************

$f = fopen("CSV_PIN.csv", "r");
$i=0;
$j=0;
global $var;
global $aux;
global $module_id;
global $analise;
$teste=0;
$val=0;

while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false)
{
if(strlen($line[0])>0)
{
    $aux[$j]= $line;
    $j++;
}
}
fclose($f);


$colunas=count($aux[0]);
foreach ($aux as $qtd) {
$linhas+= count($qtd);
}

$i=0;
$j=0;

while(strlen($aux[$j][0])>0)
{
$j++;
$linhas=$j;
}
$linhas=$linhas-1;

$i=0;
$j=0;
$analisado=0;
$decisao=0;
$departamento=0;

echo "<html>";
echo"<body>";
echo"<table>";
echo "<form id='form_teste' name='tabela' method='post' action=''";
for($j=0;$j<=$linhas;$j++)
{
         echo"<tr>";
         for($i=0;$i<=$colunas;$i++)
         {          

                if($j!=0)
                {
                    if($i==4)
                    {
                        echo"<td>";
                        echo  "<select name=ANALISADO_".$analisado.">";
                        echo  "<option value=NAO>NAO</option>";
                        echo  "<option value=SIM>SIM</option>";
                        echo  "</select>";
                        echo"<td>";
                        $analisado++;

                    }

                    if($i==6)
                    {
                        echo"<td>";
                        echo  "<select name=CSV_DECISAO_".$decisao.">";
                        echo  "<option value=DEFINIR>DEFINIR</option>";
                        echo "<option value='TROCAR OPERADORA'>TROCAR OPERADORA</option>";
                        echo "<option value='RETIRAR REMOTA'>RETIRAR REMOTA</option>";
                        echo "<option value='ALTERAR REGISTRO'>ALTERAR REGISTRO</option>";
                        echo  "</select>";
                        echo"<td>";
                        $decisao++;

                    }
                    if($i==7)
                    {
                        echo"<td>";
                        echo  "<select name=CVS_DEPARTAMENTO_".$departamento.">";
                        echo  "<option value=DEFINIR>DEFINIR</option>";
                        echo "<option value='JURIDICO'>JURIDICO</option>";
                        echo "<option value='COMERCIAL'>COMERCIAL</option>";
                        echo "<option value='TECNICO'>TECNICO</option>";
                        echo  "</select>";
                        echo"<td>";
                        $departamento++;

                    }
                    if($i==0)
                    {
                        echo"<td>".$aux[$j][0]."<td>";
                        $module_id[$j]=$aux[$j][0];
                        $val++;
                    }
                    if($i==1)
                    {
                        echo"<td>".$aux[$j][1]."<td>";
                        $oid_system[$j]=$aux[$j][1];
                    }
                    if($i==2)
                    {
                        echo"<td>".$aux[$j][2]."<td>";
                        $responsavel[$j]=$aux[$j][2];
                    }
                    if($i==3)
                    {
                        echo"<td>".$aux[$j][3]."<td>";
                        $substituto[$j]=$aux[$j][3];
                    }
                    if($i==5)
                    {
                        echo"<td>".$aux[$j][5]."<td>";
                        $qualidade_sinal[$j]=$aux[$j][5];
                    }

                }
                else
                {

                    echo"<td>".$aux[$j][$i]."<td>";

                }



         }
         echo"</tr>";



}


$var=$val;



echo "<input type=submit  name=submit/>";
echo"</form>";
echo"</table>";
echo"</body>";
echo "</html>";


//***********************************
//          SERVER SIDE
//***********************************

for ($i=0;$i<$var;$i++)

{


  $analise[$i]=$_POST['ANALISADO_'.$i];
  echo"</br>";
  echo 'valor'.$i.': '.$analise[$i];
}
```